# Shows error : "not defined"while using magic function in jupyter

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, magic-function

```
d = 8.6
print '%1.0f' %(d)
```

shows error `'d' is not defined`

I am using jupyter notebook.

Using the code

```
print '%1.0f' %(8.6)
```

gives the correct value. But, it does not recognize 'd' object

Comment: It's works perfectly to me. Are you sure you don't mistyped something?

Comment: I also can't reproduce this problem with the given code example. I get `ERROR: Line magic function \`%(d)\` not found.` when typing `%(d)` on its own line.

Answer (score -1):

There is only one possible reason, putting the assignment and the use of variable **d** on the same line gives an error.

```
d = 8.6 
print '%1.0f' %(d)
```

and

```
print '%1.0f' %(d)
```

are normally working for me on jupyter notebook!